# What does it mean to be equicardinal?

Tags: matroids

I'm reading up on matroids and have run into a lemma (and proof for said lemma) stating that the bases of a matroid are equicardinal. I assume that it means the bases have the same cardinality, but they proved that fact on the previous page.

Comment: Yes that's what it means.